# Associate old domain user profiles/files to accounts on new domain

Tags: active-directory, domain, migration, files, admt

I have 2 domains, A and B. We are migrating our user profiles and computers from A to B using ADMT. Our test accounts and machines migrate fine, however the only issue is that it updates the SID, so users would lose access to their desktop/files. Is there any way to associate the accounts on domain B to the desktops they had on domain A?

I have seen some registry edits for this, but since this will end up being a very large scale migration (thousands of users and computers), changing registry by hand seems unfeasible.

I've seen people recommend ForensIT before, but before we spend money does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's what SIDHistory is for. It provides access during the transition period while resources can be repermissioned.

Comment: is there any way to do this where the user can just log in on the new account and have the same desktop/files?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with ADMT version 3.2, ADMT includes the Security Translation Wizard which allows you to replace the SIDs from the source domain with SIDs in the destination domain. If you are not using SID History, you would have run security translation in remove mode after you finished conducting the migration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc974389(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN